# Racket "first: expects a non-empty list; given: empty"

Tags: list, debugging, recursion, scheme, racket

I was writing some code that outputs a list of factorials given a list of natural numbers. So (list 1 4 3) would give (list 1 24 6). Currently Racket is giving me the error "first: expects a non-empty list; given: empty" when on the line with the (cons ......). I used the debugger to check and the code never reaches empty, is there a way to fix this?

```
(define (factorialize arr)
 (cond
    [(empty? arr) empty]
    [else (cons (factorial (first arr)) (factorialize (factorial (first (rest arr)))))]))

;;helper function
(define (factorial num)
  (cond
    [(= 0 num) 1]
    [else (* num (factorial (- num 1)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive step isn't right, why do you call `(factorialize (factorial (first (rest arr))))`? that's trying to apply `factorialize` on the result of `factorial`, which is a number and not the list expected by `factorialize`. You just need to advance the recursion by invoking the procedure on the rest of the list! Try this:

```
(define (factorialize arr)
  (cond
    [(empty? arr) empty]
    [else (cons (factorial (first arr))
                (factorialize (rest arr)))]))
```

FYI, a simpler and more idiomatic implementation would use the built-in [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) higher-order procedure:

```
(define (factorialize arr)
  (map factorial arr))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(factorialize '(1 4 3))
=> '(1 24 6)
```